# Is it possible to apply math operations from a list in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# dynamic operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207962/c-sharp-dynamic-operator)

I don't know if this is possible but let me ask:

For example I generate a simple math operation from a list

such as

```
List lstMat={=,+,-}
```

Then I generate a random value between 0-2 and select that operator from that list

such as

```
    int ir1=1;
    int ir2=2;

    int irNew=    ir1 lstMat[1] ir2 ;
    //irNew would be 3
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @dtb, well, the OP can certainly design code that accomplishes his objective (in general terms), but there's no way `ir1 lstMat[1] ir2` will ever compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of

```
List<Func<int, int, int>> lstMat = new List<Func<int, int, int>>()
{
    (x,y)=>x.CompareTo(y),
    (x,y)=>x+y,
    (x,y)=>x-y
};

int ir1=1;
int ir2=2;

int irNew= lstMat[1](ir1,ir2);
```

Comment: +1 You might want to insert `(x,y)=>x.CompareTo(y),` in the first place.