# Is it possible to store an operator in a variable

Tags: c#

I wonder if it is possible to store an operator in some kind of variable. My code should be self explanatory.

But I wonder if it is possible to store: 
<, >, >= 
in some kind of variable and use it in an if statement like I try to do in the code or if there is another approach to achieve it?

```js
String compare = "largerValue"; //largerEqualValue, equalValue
var useoperator = "";

if (compare == "largerValue") { useoperator = ">"; }
if (compare == "largerEqualValue") { useoperator = ">="; }
if (compare == "equalValue") { useoperator = "=="; }

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    if( 20 useoperator 50) { } //Is it possible to assign an "useoperator" like this in any way?
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255618/store-an-operator-in-a-variable) answer your question?

Comment: @Sweeper, I was actually finding that post also before I posted the question. I am not sure if that does exactly what I try to do. I dont think so. It seems to use only + and - when I try to use >, >=, == etc

Comment: I think you have the same question of this guy. Here is the link [C# dynamic operator [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207962/c-sharp-dynamic-operator)

Comment: The question @Sweeper linked to would need adapting but is essentially what you should do. Hint: use `Func<int,int,bool> compare = (a, b) => a > b` instead

Comment: @phuzi, yes you are right! I just noticed that this approach takes more than double the time than using a normal operator. I am not sure if is is possible to do as fast as a normal operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way could be to store the operators as delegates in a dictionary:

```
var operators = new Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, bool>>();

operators.Add("largerValue", (a, b) => a > b);
operators.Add("largerEqualValue", (a, b) => a >= b);
operators.Add("equalValue", (a, b) => a == b);
```

Then you can just retrieve and call the operator when you need it:

```
var operator = operators[compare];

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    if (operator(20, 50)) { } 
}
```

Comment: Kevin, thank you. Yes that did actually work. As a sidenote, I tried the loop using this approach and noticed that `if (operator(20, 50)) { } ` takes more than double the time as for example `if( 20 > 50) {}` but I don't know if it is possible to make it as fast as a normal operator?

Comment: @Andreas It'll always be slower, but more than double sounds a lot. Make sure you get the value from the dictionary outside of the loop

Comment: yes I thought so too. I am getting the value outside the loop and with a normal operator it takes 4 seconds and with the approach it takes 10 seconds. So it is quite slow though. I trying to optimize some code so I am not sure I can use the approach after all even that it work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, this is possible, your operator is simple boolean binary operator:

```
        Func<int, int, bool> useoperator = null;
        String compare = "largerValue"; //largerEqualValue, equalValue

        if (compare == "largerValue") { useoperator = (x,y)=> x > y; }
        if (compare == "largerEqualValue") { useoperator = (x,y)=> x >= y; }
        if (compare == "equalValue") { useoperator = (x,y)=> x == y; }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            if(useoperator(20, 50)) { }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Func which has a delegate that evaluates your result.

Checkout the below code:

```cs
Func<int, int, bool> compareFunc = null;
if (compare == "largerValue")
{
    compareFunc = (a, b) => a > b;
}

if (compare == "largerEqualValue")
{
    compareFunc = (a, b) => a >= b;
}

if (compare == "equalValue")
{
    compareFunc = (a, b) => a == b;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    if (compareFunc != null && compareFunc(20, 50))
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## But what about performance?

Running the code below (LinqPad) resulted in

> 1,000,000,000 Native operations: 358,930,064 ticks
>   1,000,000,000 Dynamic operations: 369,853,643 ticks

Since there are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond this works out at:

> 1,000,000,000 Native operations: 35,893 ms
>   1,000,000,000 Dynamic operations: 36,985 ms

```cs
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
var iterations = 1_000_000_000;

var rng = new Random();
var greaterThan = 0;

stopwatch.Start();
for (var iteration = 0; iteration < iterations; iteration++){
    var (a, b) = (rng.Next(), rng.Next());

    if (a > b) {
        greaterThan++;
    }
}
stopwatch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"{iterations:0,000} Native operations: {stopwatch.ElapsedTicks:0,000} ticks");

Expression<Func<int, int, bool>> GreaterThan = (a, b) => a > b;
var compiled = GreaterThan.Compile();

greaterThan = 0;

stopwatch.Reset();
stopwatch.Start();
for (var iteration = 0; iteration < iterations; iteration++)
{
    var (a, b) = (rng.Next(), rng.Next());

    if (compiled(a,b))
    {
        greaterThan++;
    }
}
stopwatch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"{iterations:0,000} Dynamic operations: {stopwatch.ElapsedTicks:0,000} ticks");
```

Doing the same but using a lambda (`Func<int, int, bool>`) yielded very similar results:

> 1,000,000,000 Native operations: 354,127,563 ticks
>   1,000,000,000 Dynamic operations: 401,450,782 ticks

Or:

> 1,000,000,000 Native operations: 35,412 ms
>   1,000,000,000 Dynamic operations: 40,145 ms

### Making it faster

The easy way to make the above code faster would be to remove the random number generation from within the loop. Just using 2 random numbers generated before either of the timed sections greatly reduces the the run time, to about 3.1 seconds (Native) and 7.9 seconds (Dynamic).

## Conclusion

So, while it does seem to take about twice as long to use a dynamic operation instead of the native operation, the overall performance impact will likely be swamped by the rest of the code within the loop. In short, don't worry about it until it does actually become an issue.

## Final thoughts

It is likely that there is a way to improve the performance of the dynamic check but doing so will likely reduce the maintainability of the code.

***Disclaimer:*** *The times seen here are very subjective and will depend upon the spec of the computer running the code*