# Dynamic where operator c#

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, dynamic

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207962/c-sharp-dynamic-operator) was asked 12 years ago, but since dotnet has changed so much, I wonder if there is a solution for it nowadays.

I have a model that represents the rule and operator that I want to perform:

```cs
public class RuleStatement
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the source:

```cs
public class Foo
{
   public string Path {get;set;}
   public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

I want to perform this dynamic `where` operator on the source, so only the ones that match with all the rules will be returned. Example:

```cs
List<Foo> source = new List<Foo>();
//Sample of source
source.Add(new Foo{Path="A", Value = 10});
source.Add(new Foo{Path="B", Value = 20});
source.Add(new Foo{Path="C", Value = 30});

//Scenario 1 => Expected to be true
List<RuleStatement> rules = new List<RuleStatement>();
rules.Add(new RuleStatement{Path="A", Operator = ">=", Value=10});
rules.Add(new RuleStatement{Path="B", Operator = "==", Value=20});

bool isMatch = rules.All(rule => 
   source.Any(s => s.Path == rule.Path && s.Value $"{rule.Operator}" rule.Value));

//Scenario 2 => Expected to be false
List<RuleStatement> rules = new List<RuleStatement>();
rules.Add(new RuleStatement{Path="A", Operator = ">=", Value=100});
rules.Add(new RuleStatement{Path="B", Operator = "==", Value=20});

bool isMatch = rules.All(rule => 
   source.Any(s => s.Path == rule.Path && s.Value $"{rule.Operator}" rule.Value));
```

I couldn't find any working solution for this, so is it possible to perform this dynamic `where` operation on .NET Core 5?

If it isn't possible, what could be a workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add some possible values for Value and Operator? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Because CSharp is statically typed and a compile time language a string based operator is not supported even in .NET 5.0. the post you linked has suitable workarounds for this language limitation.

Comment: Have you heard of `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` where `T` is your class. Yes you can do that with generics and the Expression class.

Comment: @WouterdeKort I added a better example of the possible values.

Comment: I will use `Dictionary<string, Func<string, RuleStatement, bool>>` where T1=Source value, T2=Rule that contains the `type` for conversion and the comparison value.

Comment: @Jimi In this special case, the dynamic expressions may be overkill. I would actually prefer your solution with the dictionary here. You should propose it as an answer.

Comment: @LionAM All right, posted a few notes about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem:
A collection of class elements, defined as:

```
List<Foo> source = new List<Foo>();

public class Foo
{
   public string Path {get;set;}
   public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

needs to be compared to a set of rules defined in another class object, defined as:

```
public class RuleStatement
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

To comply with a *Rule* specified by a `RuleStatement` object, a `Foo` element must match the `Path` property of a `RuleStatement` and a comparison, applied to the `Value` property and based on the `Operator` property, must return a positive result.

The `Operator` property is defined as a string, which makes an implementation based on implicit/explicit operators somewhat convoluted.
The test of the compliance of `Foo` elements to the specified rules is also time-sensitive.

---

A possible solution is to map the `Operator` property values to a [Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3) delegate  that performs the comparison based on the operator and, possibly, a set of other conditions specific to each operator.

A Dictionary is often used for this kind of task.
In the a simple form, it could be a `Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, bool>>`, since two `int` values are compared and a `true/false` result is expected.

The implementation could also be more *generic*, if the Foo and `RuleStatement` class can be modified/adapted. The Dictionary mapper could also be part of the `RuleStatement` class.

For example, make the Foo class implement an Interface that can be used in similar cases:

```
public interface IGenericFoos
{
    string Path { get; set; }
    int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IGenericFoos
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

The `RuleStatement` class can be changed in:

```
public class RuleStatement<T> where T : IGenericFoos
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Func<T, RuleStatement<T>, bool>> operators =
        new Dictionary<string, Func<T, RuleStatement<T>, bool>>() {
            [">="] = (T, R) => T.Value >= R.Value,
            ["<="] = (T, R) => T.Value <= R.Value,
            ["<>"] = (T, R) => T.Value != R.Value,
            ["!="] = (T, R) => T.Value != R.Value,
            ["=="] = (T, R) => T.Value == R.Value,
            ["="] = (T, R) => T.Value == R.Value,
            ["<"] = (T, R) => T.Value < R.Value,
            [">"] = (T, R) => T.Value > R.Value,
        };

    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public bool Eval(T ifoo) => ifoo.Path == Path && operators[Operator](ifoo, this);
}
```

A LINQ query that evaluates the compliance of all Foo objects to a set of rules can then be simplified to:

```
var source = new List<Foo> { ... }
var rules = new List<RuleStatement<Foo>> { ... }
// [...]
bool isMatch = rules.All(rule => source.Any(s => rule.Eval(s)));

// Or implicitly:
bool isMatch = rules.All(rule => source.Any(rule.Eval));
```

Other types of operators can be added to perform different comparison or other operations. E.g., "+" and "-" operators can be evaluated using a fixed value, e.g:

```
["+"] = (T, R) => T.Value + R.Value >= 0,
["-"] = (T, R) => T.Value - R.Value >= 0,
```

or using variable value, adding a Property (also specific overloaded Constructors, eventually) to the `RuleStatement<T>` class.
This kind of implementation gives more *flexibility* if more complex comparisons/operations may become necessary in the future.

---

If these classes cannot be modified, the Dictionary can be used as a stand-alone Field (or whatever fits) and the LINQ query can be changed (keeping the original definition shown in the OP) in:

```
bool isMatch = rules.All(rule => source
    .Any(s => s.Path == rule.Path && operators[rule.Operator](s.Value, rule.Value)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You learn something new every day. If you actually want to go with strings and code as few as possible (and perfomance doesn't matter), you could use the NuGet package `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting`:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;

s.Path == rule.Path && CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<bool>($"{s.Value} {rule.Operator} {rule.Value}").Result;
```

If performance is more important, then maybe this will be the way to go:

This is already possible since .Net Framework 3.5, but not directly with strings. But you could write a function to achieve this. For your case, you will need a switch case for the operator - and maybe it makes sense to cache the delegates.

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

var param1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
var param2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
var expr = Expression.LessThan(param1, param2);

var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int, bool>>(expr, param1, param2).Compile();

var result = func(1,2);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks buddy. I think performance is a bit critical here because it is an event-driven application, and I need to apply the evaluation on each event, and the average will be around 5k events per second. But I can also scale up the microservice so I will test both solutions.