# Evaluate expression as string, return object?

Tags: c#, reflection, runtime, compilation

Basically I have some code where when it happens, I need to set some object equal to some expression. All of this "what to do" jazz is stored as a string. So I parse it, and use reflection to find the object I am doing it to. Now I need to find out how to store the value to this object. The problem is the value could be "1", "1*(5/2)", or "some string value". It would be really cool if I could have expressions like "this.SomeProperty" or "(x > 3 ? 4 : 5)".

Also, the object it is storing to, could be a string, int, double, or float at the minimum.

Comment: Have you reviewed the StackOverflow questions in this Google search? : http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=c%23+eval+function+site:stackoverflow.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=f&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=7952a055461d2dbc

Comment: See also http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/evalcscode.aspx

Comment: I actually ending up using the `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider` to compile it as code and that works marvelously. Thankyou both for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [operators as strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174664/operators-as-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VS2008 samples included a nifty `ExpressionParser` which could be used as a generic expression parser ([VS2008 Samples](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/bb330936.aspx)). With a few small updates, and a custom factory class, we can turn it into something a bit more expressive:

```
string expression = "(1 + 2)";
var func = FunctionFactory.Create<int>(expression);
```

Or:

```
expression = "(a * b)";
var func2 = FunctionFactory.Create<int, int, int>(expression, new[] { "a", "b" });
```

The return types of these `Create` methods are `Func<>` instances, which means we get nice strongly type delegates:

```
int result = func2(45, 100); // result = 450;
```

I've push the code to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/914257)

**Update**: I've recently [blogged about this](http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=333) too.

**Update 2**, another example:

```
var person = new Person { Age = 5 };
string expression = "(Age == 5)";
var func3 = FunctionFactory.Create<Person, bool>(expression);

bool isFive = func3(person); // Should be true.
```

Comment: That is nifty. I had no idea that FunctionFactory/ExpressionParser existed. It still involves manually parsing the parameters's values, but the overall outcome of the expression is automated.

Comment: @Nick - FunctionFactory is something I chucked together around the VS2008 ExpressionParser type. Feel free to use and abuse it from the gist :-)

Comment: This is awesome. Can you create an expression without knowing the parameter list (ie *a* and *b* in your example) beforehand? Like dynamically inferring the parameters from the expression string?

Comment: @Justin - I'm not convinced that would work without modifying the `ExpressionParser` to update the included `ParameterExpression` instances used to match the parameters. The problem I think would be that you probably couldn't differentiate between what is an operand (you pass in), and a property of a `this` instance (see update above).

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen http://ncalc.codeplex.com ?

It's extensible, fast (e.g. has its own cache) enables you to provide custom functions and varaibles at run time by handling EvaluateFunction/EvaluateParameter events. Example expressions it can parse:

```
Expression e = new Expression("Round(Pow(Pi, 2) + Pow([Pi2], 2) + X, 2)"); 

  e.Parameters["Pi2"] = new Expression("Pi * Pi"); 
  e.Parameters["X"] = 10; 

  e.EvaluateParameter += delegate(string name, ParameterArgs args) 
    { 
      if (name == "Pi") 
      args.Result = 3.14; 
    }; 

  Debug.Assert(117.07 == e.Evaluate());
```

It also handles unicode & many data type natively. It comes with an antler file if you want to change the grammer. There is also a fork which supports MEF to load new functions.