# I have a Textbox.Text which content is 1+1. How to I convert this into double and store it in i?

Tags: c#

I have
i = double.Parse(TextBox.Text);
but when I enter the + symbol, this error appear "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'"

Comment: This has been asked a lot before. It's a specific version of "how do I compile and execute C# code dynamically?". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18

Comment: You want 1+ 1 to be converted to 2 ?

Comment: 1) `double` is not an integer type. 2) Such parse methods are intended for strings containing numbers. That is not what you have here.

Comment: Your question is [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174664/operators-as-strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a much larger issue than you think.

Your textbox has a string. In this case, "1+1" is the value in your textbox. However, that cannot be parsed to an integer value because it contains the plus sign. The plus sign is a character, it is not an integer (0,1,2,3,4..). So, what you get is a data type conversion conflict.

From what I gather, you'd like to evaluate that expression and then store the value into into the i variable. In this case, you would like i to equal 2.

You will need to evaluate the string and convert it into a formula then use the result to store in the variable.

Here's a link to an example of a conversion formula.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7f62b87d-a35c-4074-a0f0-84a9dd7ff0a5/convert-string-to-formula?forum=csharpgeneral